# Setting the max size visble for Time Machine shares

Tags: samba

I have a quick question on a time machine share that I've set up.
I am wondering how to set the max size for a time machine share in the smb.conf file. Shown below is the smb.conf file I have at the moment

```
[general]
#added at the end f general section 
min protocol = SMB2
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
fruit:metadata = stream
fruit:model = MacSamba
fruit:posix_rename = yes
fruit:veto_appledouble = no
fruit:wipe_intentionally_left_blank_rfork = yes
fruit:delete_empty_adfiles = yes

# added for samba sharing for mac
[tm@rp]
    comment = TM_Backups
    path = /media/backups/tm
    valid users = rpuser
    read only = no
    vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
    fruit:time machine = yes
    fruit:time machine max size = 1.5T

[other_backups@rp]
    comment = Other_Backups
    path = /media/backups/other
    valid users = rpuser
    read only = no
    vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr

[files@rp]
    comment = Nas
    path = /media/nas/files
    valid users = rpuser
    read only = no
    vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
```

But when I look at the info in the time machine as shown below it says the full size of the volume is available, not 1.5 Terabytes as specified in the conf file .[image]

Just wondering if it is normal or if it is not, where I am going wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There was a quirk where the size was not reported correctly until the first backup was complete on zfs.  The fix was to exclude lots of folders, run a backup and then include the skipped folders on the second and subsequent backups!  Not sure if it was ever fixed or was dependent on the Linux file system on the disks. Because of this I partitioned the drive and moved back to NETATALK for TineMachine backups...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll have a look and see if it works.